# Uniform randomization of visits yields Poisson process - well-known?

Tags: probability-theory, reference-request, uniform-distribution, poisson-process

From various experiments, I seem to have rediscovered the following idea

> **Proposition** (*Uniform randomization of visits yields Poisson process*). Suppose that a process iteratively visits elements in a set where each visit selects an element at equal probability (uniform distribution across the set). Let $z$ be the time it would take to scan all of the elements once (scan the set). Then from the perspective of any given element, the visits arrive as a Poisson process with rate $\zeta = 1/z$.

I say *rediscovered* because I suspect that the above proposition is a consequence of well-known principles of Poisson processes.  However, I haven't found anything explicit.  Where might I find something?

*My sketch proof of the proposition*: Choose a target element from the set. Let $T$ be the time to between visits to the target. It is sufficient to show that $T$ has an exponential distribution with rate parameter $\zeta$ as this occurs if and only if the target is receiving visits as a Poisson process with rate $\zeta$. Partition the set into $n$ subsets that require equal durations to scan. By construction, the target can reside in only one subset. Moreover each subset takes duration $\tfrac{d}{n}$ to scan at so $m$ visits will take duration $m\tfrac{d}{n}$. Now for any $t>0$
$$
  \mathbb{P}(T \leq t) = 1 - \mathbb{P}(T > t)
$$
Put $m = \tfrac{tn}{d}$ so that $m$ visits take duration $t$. Consequently $T > t$ occurs if and only if there are $m$ visits that each miss the target hence
$$\begin{align*}
  \mathbb{P}(T \leq t) &= 1 - \mathbb{P}(\text{$m$ visits that each miss the target})
\\
  &= 1 - \left( \frac{n-1}{n} \right)^m
\end{align*}$$
as each visit selects a subset at equal probability and there are $n-1$ subsets that do not contain the target. Therefore
$$\begin{align*}
  \mathbb{P}(T \leq t) &= 1 - \left( \left(1- \frac{1}{n} \right)^n \right)^{\frac{m}{n}}
\\
&= 1 - \left( \left(1- \frac{1}{n} \right)^n \right)^{\zeta t}
\\
&\rightarrow 1 - \exp(-\zeta t) & \text{as $n \to \infty$}
\end{align*}$$
which is the cumulative distribution function for the exponential distribution with rate parameter $\zeta$, as required.

Comment: Informally, it makes perfect sense. If we denote by $T$ the amount of time until the next arrival, then $P(T > s) = P(T > t+s \mid P > t)$ for all $t$. The proces is memoryless.

Comment: Consider the case where in which the set is $\{1,\ldots,6\}$. The process is then akin to rolling a die repeatedly, and you're asking how long it will take until you roll a $6$. The answer should be independent of how long it's been since you last rolled a $6$ --- a die has no memory, after all!

Comment: The only remark is that a Poisson process typically has continuous times rather than integer times. In the long-run limit (or, equivalently, really-short-time-intervals limit), however, the distinction blurs, so it's reasonable that you find back the exponential distribution only as you let $n \to \infty$. (But I should make the disclaimer that I did not read the sketch proof carefully.)

Answer (score 1):

What I have rediscovered is the convergence in distribution of $X/n$ to an exponential distribution where $X$ has a geometric distribution with $p=1/n$. Each of the visits is a Bernoulli trial, and the condition of "counting the number of visits until the revisited element is selected" is equivalent to $X$.

See "The Geometric Distribution" in "Section 3.8: Convergence in Distribution" of Siegrist, Kyle (2020, August 10) *Probability, Mathematical Statistics, and Stochastic Processes*. Retrieved June 24, 2021, from https://stats.libretexts.org/@go/page/10148